# RSpec have_selector with request and request.body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, capybara

Why would

`response.body.should have_selector "result"`

pass and

`response.should have_selector "result"`

not pass?

I understand `ActionController::TestResponse` is returned as the `response` and `response.body` is a `String`.

Does have_selector only work on strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response is the whole response object, which contains lots of different properties. It is not a string, and have_selector tests for a string.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just verifying since this is something that broke when moving from have_tag to have_selector. ]